# sed command to find .css file inside link

Tags: sed

I am using sed to read the .css file name (after "href=") from an html file. The command is follow:

```
cssFiles=$(echo "$BODY" | sed -rn 's/<link\s.*href=\W(.*.css).*/\1/p')
```

But, it does not works correctly. Below, sample input, output and expected output is given. Where am I wrong?

Sample input:

```
<link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/flexslider/flexslider.css">
```

Sample output:

```
/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css
js/flexslider/flexslider.css
```

Expected output:

```
/css/default.css
js/flexslider/flexslider.css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cssFiles=$(echo "$BODY" | sed -rn 's/<link\s.*href=\W(.*.css).*/\1/p' | awk -F'=' '{print$2}'  awk -F' ' '{print$1}')
```